# Pandas Dataframe show Count with Group by and Aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this data

```
ID  Value1  Value2  Type    Type2
1   3          1    A       X
2   2          2    A       X
3   5          3    B       Y
4   2          4    B       Z
5   6          8    C       Z
6   7          9    C       Z
7   8          0    C       L
8   3          2    D       M
9   4          3    D       M
10  6          5    D       M
11  8          7    D       M
```

Right now i am able to generate this output using this code

```
pandabook.groupby(['Type','Type2'],as_index=False)['Value1', 'Value2'].agg({'Value1': 'sum','Value2': 'sum'})


ID  Value 1 Value2  Type    Type2
1   5          3    A         X
2   5          3    B         Y
3   2          5    B         Z
4   13        17    C         Z
5   8          0    C         L
6   21        17    D         M
```

I want to show the Aggregated count as well, as show in this example

[image]

How can i achieve this output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new value to dictionary with `size` function, remove `as_index=False` for prevent:

> ValueError: cannot insert Type, already exists

and last `rename` with `reset_index`:

```
df = pandabook.groupby(['Type','Type2']).agg({'Value1': 'sum','Value2': 'sum', 'Type':'size'})
df = df.rename(columns={'Type':'Count'}).reset_index()
print (df)
  Type Type2  Value1  Value2  Count
0    A     X       5       3      2
1    B     Y       5       3      1
2    B     Z       2       4      1
3    C     L       8       0      1
4    C     Z      13      17      2
5    D     M      21      17      4
```

Comment: Hi, i have made changes to the post. please have a look.

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar - [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), because not possible copy it. Can you convert data to text?

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar - Can yiou check solution now?

Comment: yes, it worked .You are like a super genius of Pandas.

Comment: There is one thing, i could not understand the need of renaming.

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar - because there is MultiIndex name `Type` and `Type` column, som raised error, because pandas not working nice with duplicated columns names.